# Application response times are high with cometd calls

Tags: salesforce, http-status-code-403, loadrunner, cometd

while executing performance test of salesforce application there are  transactions with *cometd* calls. For such transactions, either the response time is high or I'm getting forbidden error "**unknown client**" in the response.

Is there anything which needs to be done from scripting perspective? P.S. - I am using Load runner for scripting.

**Request**

[{“id “:=”5”,” channel”=”/meta/connect”, “connection type”=”long polling”, “client id”= “####”}]

**Response**

"advice": {
"interval": 0,
"reconnect": "handshake"
},
"channel": "/meta/connect",
"id": "5",
"error": "403::Unknown client",
"successful": false,
}

Please note:
1)sdfc-stream cookie is consistent throughout
2)Authorization < token> header is added in the request

Comment: You should be coordinating any Salesforce related performance testing with a named contact at Salesforce per your organization end user license agreement with Salesforce.  They approve your plan, define when and where you may direct your load.  What does your main salesforce contact say?

Answer (score 1):

The `/meta/connect` channel is a reserved channel used for the CometD heartbeat, and when using HTTP it performs "long-polling".

As such, it is natural that the request is held by the server for a longer time.

You must not use any `/meta/*` channel for load testing, but broadcast or service channel (see [here](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_concepts_channels) for the channel definitions).

Not specific to SalesForce, but the CometD project has its own benchmark, see https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_benchmarking.
You should look at that as an example about how to perform a correct benchmark for CometD.